# hystrix HealthCounts getTotalRequests result seems wrong

Tags: java, metrics, hystrix

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    MyCommand c = new MyCommand();
    c.execute();        
    HealthCounts hc = c.getMetrics().getHealthCounts();
    System.out.println("Total request num：" + hc.getTotalRequests());
}
```

MyCommand extends HystrixCommand and its run method do nothing：

```
protected String run() throws Exception {
        return "";
}
```

When I run the code, output as following:

```
Total request num：0
Total request num：1
Total request num：2
```

I think output should looks like:

```
Total request num：1
Total request num：2
Total request num：3
```

Why?